# Capturing first group and separately third + fourth group (REGEX)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create two separate regexes that capture two specific parts of a string:

Example string: `3027-20171110020655-test-5`

I need to capture first: `3027` and second: `test-5`
The second group may not always have a hyphen in it.

I have so far created: `[^\-]+` 
This creates 4 separate capture groups -- I'm not sure how to narrow it down further.

Comment: Try [`^(\d+)-\d+?\-([a-z]+\-?\d)*`](https://regex101.com/r/68hEMt/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `^` token to mark the beginning of the string:

```
^[^\-]+
```

Then, depending on how your input is formatted, you don't need separate regex's, just put whatever you are trying to capture into capturing groups, using parentheses (`()`)

```
^([^\-]+)-\d+-(.*)
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/T2BIrE/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex using negated character classes and anchors:

```
^([^-]+)-[^-]*-([^-]+)(?:-([^-]+))?$
```

Where last group is an optional match.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xZLqeT/1)